# Testing kIsWeb constant in flutter

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

in my code i have a `lookup` method:

***lookup.dart***

```
Future<http.Response> httpLookup(String address) {
    return kIsWeb
        ? _httpClient.get(address)
        : _httpClient.get(
            Uri.https(address, ''),
          );
  }
```

how can i test the `kIsWeb` constant during unit testing? this is what i have tried so far but the coverage is not going though.

***lookup_test.dart***

```
@TestOn('browser')
void main (){
test('shoud test lookup', () {
    InternetLookup lookup = InternetLookup();
    when(mockInternetLookup.httpLookup(any))
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => http.Response('success', 200));
    lookup.httpLookup('www.google.com');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can to use an Interface and to mock it.

> 

```
abstract class IAppService {
  bool getkIsWeb();
}

class AppService implements IAppService {
  bool getkIsWeb() {
    return kIsWeb;
  }
}
```

In the tests, you must to use like as

```
class MockAppService extends Mock implements IAppService {}
```

...

```
when(appService.getkIsWeb())
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to actually run it in a web environment with

```
flutter test --platform chrome
```

You can also add

```dart
@TestOn('browser')
```

at the top of your test file so your tests are only run when the platform is a browser.

Look at [`TestOn`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/test_api.scaffolding/TestOn-class.html) and its [README](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/tree/master/pkgs/test#platform-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add an optional parameter and decorate it with @visibleForTesting to override the `kIsWeb` constant:

```dart
Future<http.Response> httpLookup(String address, { @visibleForTesting bool isTestingForWeb = false}) {
  return kIsWeb || isTestingForWeb ? ...
}
```